# What were the last set of flashes of memory about?

Tags: plot-explanation, stay

In the film **Stay**.

After Henry dies and is put on the stretcher, Sam talks to Laila. He thanks her for the help. After which, he asks her out to coffee. Right then there are flashes of Sam and Laila from the world of Henry. What's happening here? What do these flashes indicate. Prior to this all of the other parts of the movie were what Henry was seeing in his head. Now that Henry is dead...

... what do these flashes indicate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Henry is actually seeing Lila as Athena in a flashback. Additionally, the flashbacks coming from Sam of he and Lila are constructed by [Henry](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0371257/synopsis?ref_=tt_stry_pl).

Henry was in a dream-like state throughout the movie. In dreams, the mind can extract a myriad of people and can often pull from the subconscious. Our subconscious can conjure people from random events in our life we come in contact with while awake.

Henry's dreams are taking reality and twisting it into a new perspective.  **Henry's new perspective is that Sam's dreams are a way for Henry's mind to solve or make sense of a real situation featuring Sam.  The audience is shown this through Sam's "eyes", but through Henry's perspective.

When a person dies, their brain can still "fire" neurons.  This can cause hallucinations, clarity or seeing flashes of light that can trigger a random, non-eventful memory.

Henry's brain can still produce memories, even though he is considered legally dead.  He is simply producing these memories through Sam.

Comment: Thanks for that. While you mention that those flashes are constructed by Henry, the wiki article suggests that they were drawn into the other world. If flashes are constructed by Henry it has to be seen by Henry too. Not the others. So the question is how is Sam all of a sudden seeing flashes?

Comment: @Tivep I added a few paragraphs in the beginning of the answer.  This movie can be interpreted so many ways.  I am giving you my interpretation of it based on what I took away from the movie.  I hope it helps :)

Comment: I completely understand why Henry is seeing the dream based on the bystanders. His mind is fading and in a bit of a trance. The question is, why is Sam seeing it?

Comment: @Tivep Sam is seeing these flashes from Henry's perspective.   The viewers are shown Henry's perspective being "channeled" if you will, through Sam's eyes.  This is allowing the viewers to see that Henry is seeing something of a last wish, but through Sam, knowing that it had to be through Sam, since Henry was dying.

Comment: interesting @steelerfan. But, at the time Sam sees the flashes, Henry is already dead. No more Henry, no more perspective, right?

Comment: @Tivep I am quoting one of your above comments.  "His mind is fading and is in a bit of a trance." :)

Comment: @steelerfan, yes but that was up until when he's on the road. After that he dies. They declare him dead, only after that does Sam ask Laila for coffee.

Comment: @Tivep His mind is fading...he is declared dead.  When people are legally dead, their brain neurons can still fire,  often causing hallucinations, moments of clarity or seeing bright flashes of light, triggering random memories of people/places.  Just because he is declared dead does not mean that his brain still cannot produce thse images.  Several times, I have witnessed a person removed from life support.  The Dr. calls time of death.  A word or noise is uttered from the deceased.  It happens frequently.  This is why I have this interpretation of the film.  I hope this makes sense :)

Comment: @steelerfan, WOAH .. so you're saying he's declared dead but his mind continues to fade right till the end when Sam's asking her out for coffee. I like this explanation better than the wiki link you quoted. I don't like the "drawn into the other world". Yours is way more sound. Do add that to the answer for other readers. Think readers might miss the info in the comments. Accept!